# MSBuild ExecuteDDL fails in .NET Framework 4.0

Tags: .net, msbuild, msbuild-task

I have migrated my project from .NET 3.5 to 4.0 and hence I am using MSBuild.exe of C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319 instead of C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5. This is causing ***ExecuteDDL*** task failure. Please help.
Cheers,
Nabin

Comment: Sure, that's enough information to go on.  Not.  Exceptions?  Inner exceptions?  Event logs?  Build logs?

Comment: The "ExecuteDDL" task failed unexpectedly.
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo, Version=9.0.242.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo, Version=9.0.242.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91'
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName fileName, String codeBase, Evidence assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly locationHint, StackCrawlMark&amp;

Answer (score 1):

"Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo, Version=9.0.242.0,"

Looks like it's looking for the SQL Server 2005 client tools, do you have these installed?

Answer (score 1):

The ExecuteDDL task from MSBuild community tasks uses the Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo assembly.  The assembly is loaded dynamically and it trys to load the following assemblies in the following order:

- Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91
- Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo, Version=9.0.242.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91

So it tries to load 10.0 (Sql Server 2008), then 9.0 (Sql Server 2005).  If it can't find either of these it fails with the exception you received.

Sql Server puts these in the GAC by default, so check to see if these are on your machine first.  If that doesn't solve your problem let me know.  I wrote the task and I'll get some more info from you and get it working.

**Update**

Sql Server 2008 Support wasn't added until 03/2009 and unfortunately the official releases are older than that.  Grab the nightly build from http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/ which has a lot of bug fixes:

- [Zip File](http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Nightly.zip)
- [MSI Installer](http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Nightly.msi)

Comment: The GAC is having version 10.0.0.0 but it does not have 9.0.242.0. However MSBuild of Framework 3.5 is working fine whereas MSBuild of framework 4.0 throws exception.

Comment: I confirmed that this task works just fine with MSBuild 4.0.  Try getting the latest version.  I updated my answer above.

Comment: I can confirm getting the latest nightly build instead fixes the problem. The latest release which you would naturally go for by default is seriously old!